# How to store 2gb above size file in file stream table?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to store 2 gb above file in file stream table, i am getting will declare the size of byte array using file stream length using below code

```
                     Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream
                     fs = File.Open(fpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
                     Dim filelen As Long = fs.Length
                     Dim buffer(fs.Length - 1) As Byte ' Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. error
                     fs.Read(buffer, 0, filelen)
                     fs.Close()
```

So any other way to store above 2 gb file ?
Blob not support, so MS bring file stream concept, but .NET array not support above 255 .

I tried this code from reply from one of the friend, but still problem

```
Dim fs As FileStream
     fs = File.Open(fpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
     Dim filelen As Long = fs.Length
     Dim buffer As New List(Of Byte())
     Dim len = Int32.MaxValue / 2
     Dim mk As Long = 0
     While (filelen - len > 0)
         Dim file(len) As Byte
         fs.Read(file, mk, len)
         buffer.Add(file)
         filelen -= len
         mk += len
     End While  '--- when reach first time then nothing happen
     fs.Close()
```

Pls any suggestion will appreciate.

Thanks and Regards
Aravind

Comment: You aren't using `fs.Read` correctly. You need to call it in a loop **and check the returned value**.

Comment: What do you mean by "file stream table"?

Comment: You're getting errors because you're trying to allocate a 2GB+ sized buffer **in memory**. You don't want to do that.

Comment: Any other solution pls..